# Creating a wifi subnetwork inside another wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, subnet

When connected to a public wifi network that I don't trust, I want to be able to:

- Connect multiple computers to the internet using wifi, through a VPN, without having to install VPN client software on each computer
- Transfer data between my computers using wifi, without anyone else on the public network able to intercept the data.
- Run programs that require open ports (like SSH or FTP) on one of my computers without having to worry about anyone else on the public network potentially trying to connect to them.

Questions:

1. Is it right that I want is my own subnetwork inside the original network? Or what is the correct technical name for what I want to do?
2. What kind of router or other hardware is necessary to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have computers A and B with you and want to share information between them while connect to the same public WiFi. Without using additional vpn software installed on your machines, any other form of VPN (like the options built into windows 7 and 10) are not secure enough to be viable. Even if you use an adhoc connection, this is still wireless. Data is broadcast over the air in all directions. If you only want computer A on the internet and B could be local only. Maybe get a small switch to plug them in local. Of course you could always get a crossover cable and set that up too. WiFi is nearly impossible to make 100% secure.